# 2 problems in real analysis about supremum norm metric

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space with distance $dX$. Defined the metric space
$C(X)$ with the distance associated with the sup-norm $d(f,g)= \sup|f(x)−g(x)|
x\in X$. 
But could someone help me Show that $C(X)$ is connected but not compact

Comment: Do you want to show that $C(X)$ is compact or not compact?

Comment: I think C（X）is connected but not compact

Comment: So what did you mean by "By the way, I can show it's compact..."?

Comment: I thought the compactness may  help us to prove that C is connect..

Comment: Please revise your question. It is not very understandable.

Comment: sorry about that I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connectedness: Given $f, g \in C(X)$, define a path $F:I \times C(X)$ by $F(t,x) = (1 - t)f(x) + tg(x)$. Show that $F$ is continuous. Then you can conclude that $C(X)$ is path-connected.

Cover $C(X)$ with open balls of radii $1$, $2$, $\ldots$ centered at the origin (zero function). This covering has no finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks！I forgot to use path-connected..

Answer (score 1):

The compactness portion of the problem can be handled if you apply the Arzela-Ascoli theorem correctly.

Comment: y，but do I need to give some specific restrictions to the metric space X？

Comment: The space $C(X)$ is never going to be compact, not even in the trivial case in which $X$ is reduced to a single element.